# Fail to convert strings into variables for dict value assignment?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, exec, global

I am currently writing a lambda function (python 3.9) with the objective of finding students who are celebrating holiday in their respective country. To start off, I have a student.json file and a folder containing all the countries' holiday in the `holiday_folder` in my S3 bucket:

```
    (main directory)
    student.json
    holiday_folder
     (within holiday_folder)
     holiday_us.json
     holiday_cn.json
     holiday_my.json
     holiday_th.json
     the list goes on...
```

The `student.json` file has the following content:

```
{'student': [{'name':'Adam', 'location':'US'}, {'name':'Ben', 'location':'SG'}...]}
```

While all the holiday json files are structured similarly as follow:

```
{ "holiday_us":[ { "date":"20220101", "desc":"New Year's Day" }, {"date"....}]}
```

To achieve my objective, I:

1. json.loads `student.json` content into variable `student`
2. Create a list called `countries` and run a for loop to append only the "location" values of all students in `student` variable
3. Create another list called `holiday_calendar` to store transformed location values a.k.a. transforming ['US', 'SG', ...] into ['holiday_us', 'holiday_sg' ...] so that I can convert these list values into variable names to load holiday dates
4. Run a conditional for loop on `student`. The loop will look into the holiday list that's only relevant to the specific student and return value accordingly. I wont be going deep on this as this is not the point of the question.

   ```
    countries = []
    holiday_calendar = []
    for i in range(len(student)):
        if student[i]['location'] not in countries:
            countries.append(student[i]['location'])
            holiday_calendar.append('holiday_' + student[i]['location'].lower())

    print(holiday_calendar) # output: ['holiday_us', 'holiday_sg'...]

    for i in range(0, len(holiday_calendar)):

        print(holiday_calendar[i])
        locals[holiday_calendar[i]] = json.loads(s3.Object('my_s3_bucket', 'holiday_folder' + holiday_calendar[i] + '.json')).get()['Body'].read())
   ```

My issue is that I cannot convert the `holiday_calendar` list values into variables. When I ran the above code, I got this error:

```
"errorMessage": "'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment",
"errorType": "TypeError"
```

I am pretty sure the error came from the globals() line as I have ran all the other parts of the code and they all worked flawlessly. I have also tried exec() and locals() as per suggested in a lot of SO topics but none worked. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did none of the topics suggest using a dictionary instead? Globals, locals and especially exec should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: @matszwecja Do you mean declaring a new dict variable and assigning the string and json.load content as key-value pair? I am looking to have the variable storing the content, and not dict[variable] = content (if you get me)

Comment: `dict[variable] = content` is the proper way to do that. Trying to make `globals[]`, `locals[]` or `exec()` work will cause you even more problems down the line. There is precisely 0 reason to use those in your case.

Comment: @matszwecja Alright, thanks for the input. I will try the dict method now.